# Running App Script with output on a different Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have found a script that pulls data from a cell and adds a row to the bottom of the Google Sheet, but I want to be able to have the output on a separate sheet called "Data". Here is the script:

```
function recordValue() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Channels");
var date = new Date();
var value =sheet.getRange("B9").getValue();
sheet.appendRow([date,value])
}
```

I know I need to change the `sheet.appendRow` but I don't know what I need to get it to another sheet, say in cell A2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must declare the second sheet.

```
function recordValue() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Channels");
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
  var date = new Date();
  var value = sheet.getRange("B9").getValue();
  dataSheet.appendRow([date,value])
}
```

See:

- [The Modern JavaScript Tutorial](https://javascript.info/)

Comment: Ah thank you for this! If I may ask one more favor... how can I get it so its in a certain cell on the new page and just doesn't add a new row?

Comment: Look into `.getRange()` and `.setValue()`/`.setValues()` within the Google Apps Script documentation!

Answer (score -1):

#### Outputting on a different sheet

```
function recordValue() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Channels");
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName("Data")
  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1,2),setValues([[new Date(),sh.getRange("B9").getValue()]]);
}
```

- [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))

Comment: I'm getting this error:
Syntax error: SyntaxError: Identifier 'sh' has already been declared line: 14 file: Data Grab.gs

Comment: Corrected the problem